# Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument for rgb image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find how many pixels in an image are with a color range of the same pixel of a different image. Both images I am using are rgb. I wanted to use something like this to be able to do it but I keep
getting the Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument.

```
difference = cv2.absdiff(imageA, imageB)
b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)
```

I have tried classifing that images as an numpy array, but then I get the error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) for the split function. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Check the shape and dtype of imageA and imageB before absdiff()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that `imageA` and `imageB` share the same number of channels and the same width and height:

   ```
   assert(imageA.shape == imageB.shape)
   ```
2. Make sure that the type of the images are equal to each other:

   ```
   assert(imageA.dtype == imageB.dtype)
   ```

I suspect that (1) or (2) is `False`.  To compute the absolute difference in OpenCV, the data types as well as the sizes should be exactly the same.  Make sure that both (1) and (2) are `True` before calling `cv2.absdiff`.  `cv2.split` is agnostic of the incoming data type so the problem shouldn't be there.

Also, given your error message when using a NumPy array, this is leading me to believe that one image is grayscale and the other is colour.  That makes sense as when you try and do a `cv2.split`, it only provides one channel as opposed to three.  You want to make sure you are comparing apples with apples, so you can do a check to see if the image is grayscale and convert to colour when necessary.  You can create a "colour" image from a grayscale image by simply duplicating the channels.  That can be done under the hood using [`cv2.cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) and providing the right flag.  In this case that would b `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` (assuming you used `cv2.imread` to read in your images, which I suspect is the case).

Therefore:

```py
if len(imageA.shape) == 2:
    imageA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
if len(imageB.shape) == 2:
    imageB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

difference = cv2.absdiff(imageA, imageB)
b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)
```

Comment: I am sure this would have solved the issues in most cases. Mine was me just being stupid and forgetting that i flattened it in another part while testing something else and not undoing it.

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov Ah - I didn't see that part of your code!  Glad you figured it out!